# Python: Como as rotas dinâmicas do Flask são implementadas?

Tags: python, característica-linguagem, flask

Eu comecei a estudar um pouco sobre desenvolvimento Web com Flask. O framework trata componentes dinâmicos da URL da seguinte forma:

```py
@app.route('/<comp_dinamico>')
def page(comp_dinamico):
    # codigo
    return '%s' % comp_dinamico
```

O que eu queria entender é como a substring em `'/<comp_dinamico>'` vira uma variável. Ou se isso não é uma variável, gostaria de entender o que é. Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Você quer criar o seu proprio framework é isso? Porque se não for não tem sentido de entender como o nucleo funciona até chegar neste ponto, agora se for tem algum sentido.

Comment: "não tem sentido entender como funciona" ?? Errado - não se deve usar coisas "por que sim" - é bom entender por que funciona sim - só não é necessário saber fazer igual.

Comment: Só queria entender como funciona por curiosidade mesmo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Flask decompõe sua URL em partes para funções que dão match nela. Por exemplo, digamos que você tem uma URL para ver os dados de um usuário que é `/user/1`.

Declarar um decorator que dá match para essa URL seria assim:

```
@app.route('/user/<user_id>')
def my_user(user_id):
    pass
```

Sabendo que esse decorator é um match para sua rota, ele injeta a parte da URL com o valor dinâmico nos parâmetros dela.

Esse padrão é encontrado em vários frameworks como, Django, Laravel, etc.

Normalmente é uso de expressões regulares que proporcionam essa funcionalidade.